# EJB Timer JEE6 does not starts automatically

Tags: timer, java-ee-6

Why this time does not work? What am I missing?

I'm using GlassFish 3.1.2.

```
package foo.bar;

import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class MySimpleTimerEJB {

    @Schedule(second="*/1")
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: "The second, minute, and hour attributes have a default value of 0." Try setting minute=* and hour=*

Answer (score 2):

Solved,

as [Piotr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920607/piotr-nowicki) suggested, i have to inform minute and hour aswell, since they have a default zero value.

also i used the persistent=false attribute, and got the expected result.

```
@Schedule(second="*", minute="*",hour="*", persistent=false)
public void foo() {
    System.out.println("Foo");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the scheduling counter starts immediately after the deployement you have to add the @startup annotation so the container will handle and start scheduling management

Comment: Hello Jason, i've tried that too. What Piotr Nowicki suggested worked to me. Thanks for the answer